# javascript indexed array variance math with matching dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, math, d3.js

let's say there's an indexed array with 2 objects, each with some dates and values. What's the best way to calculate variance of values from the object containing `"other"` key, vs. the object that is the `"baseline"`, while matching the dates?

Please note that dates sometimes line up but not always. Also assume dates are valid parsed dates.

Note that the indexed array is generated by `d3.nest().key().entries()` from a CSV for graphing. It's possible to pre-calculate in CSV but there are a lot of objects and baseline could change on the fly.

```
array = [
    {
        key: "baseline",
        values: [
            {
                date: "Jan 1 2013", // assume valid parsed date
                value: 100
            },
            {
                date: "Jan 2 2013",
                value: 150
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        key: "other",
        values: [
            {
                date: "Jan 2 2013", // note dates do not line up
                value: 1000
            },
            {
                date: "Jan 3 2013",
                value: 2000
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Desired result:

```
desiredResult = [
    {
        key: "baseline",
        values: [
            {
                date: "Jan 1 2013", // assume valid parsed date
                value: 100,
                delta: 0 // 0 because it's the baseline
            },
            {
                date: "Jan 2 2013",
                value: 150,
                delta: 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        key: "other",
        values: [
            {
                date: "Jan 2 2013",
                value: 1000,
                delta: 6.666666666666667 // 1000 / 150
            },
            {
                date: "Jan 3 2013", // note dates do not line up
                value: 2000,
                delta: null // null because there's no date match
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood, the following should do it:

*PS: I believe that your example is wrong since Jan 2 2013 has a baseline of 150, not 100*.

```
function applyDeltas(arr, baseline) {
    //find baseline values
    arr.some(function (item) {
        return item.key === baseline && (baseline = item.values);
    });

    //build a date index for quick lookups
    baseline = baseline.reduce(function (res, item) {
        res[item.date] = item.value;
        return res;
    }, {});

    arr.forEach(function (item) {
        item.values.forEach(function (valItem) {
            var bl = baseline[valItem.date],
                val = valItem.value;

            valItem.delta = typeof bl !== 'undefined'? (bl === val? 0 : val / bl) : null;
        });
    });
}

applyDeltas(array, 'baseline');
```

Comment: Thanks, this works very well and the higher order functions keeps it concise. You're correct there was a mistake in the example, edited.